# avrdude only showing no output, blocking terminal (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, avr, avrdude

I tried installing avrdude on Ubuntu to program an Atmega328P. However, when trying to get the signature of the µC, it only gives me a blank output. When using verbose mode, it does show the following:

```
     avrdude: Version 6.3
     Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
     Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

     System wide configuration file is "/etc/avrdude.conf"
     User configuration file is "/root/.avrduderc"
     User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

     Using Port                    : usb
     Using Programmer              : usbasp
```

But, from what I saw on Google, this is normal output?

At first I thought it might have something to do with the USBasp (even though it worked before, on Windows), but... I noticed that when I pull it out when it is in its blocked mode, it gives the following output:

```
  avrdude: error: could not find USB device with vid=0x16c0 pid=0x5dc vendor='www.fischl.de' product='USBasp'
  avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Because it detects when it is pulled out, it seems to me that finding the usb dongle is not the issue?

I noticed I get the same error if I wait several minutes.

I also noticed that there is no difference between this behaviour with USBasp actually connected to a µC or not.

This is the command I use:

```
avrdude -P usb -c usbasp -p atmega328p -v
```

Any clue what might cause the issue here?

Comment: @Akshaybarahate avrdude is not server- or networking related. It's about microcontroller programming. I thought about posting it in EE SE at first, but when I used the SE-Search, it showed close to all avrdude questions posted in Stack Overflow. Also: Stack overflow has the avrdude tags. That's why I thought this would be the most appropriate place.

Comment: I have will delete my comment. Thank for clarifying

Answer (score 0):

> avrdude: error: could not find USB device with vid=0x16c0 pid=0x5dc vendor='www.fischl.de' product='USBasp'

Did you install USBasp drivers? AVRdude is software for programmators/programmers but you need to install drivers for your device, as we can see USBasp. There is original [website](https://www.fischl.de/usbasp/) with drivers but I'm using it on Windows so you have to find tutorial for installing drivers on your OS.

Okay, when you done you could be able to read signature of your MCU by typing `avrdude -c {programmer_name} -p {chip_id}` . You can check that AVRDude is properly installed by typing:

- `avrdude -p ?` for all avaliable chips
- `avrdude -c ?` for all avaliable programmers.

Comment: your own link says "On Linux and MacOS X no kernel driver is needed. Windows requires a driver for USBasp.".
Also: I tested it on a different computer, and on that one it works like a charm. Seems like there's something off with this machine.

Comment: I know I saw this on this link but I had same problem when I didn't installed USBasp drivers properly.

Comment: Reading the signature is the first thing I tried. it gave the behaviour described above. On the 2nd machine however, it worked flawlessly.
Both your other commands show the help-output because they are wrong.

Comment: What drivers do you suggest I install then? There are none as far as I'm aware. avrdude uses the hardware directly.

Comment: Afaik there a plenty of tutorial on web with step by step solution to program your chip on Linux. But in short, you need to have compiler with extended avr librariers, avrdude to use your programmer and drivers for your programmer.